# как задать гравитацию в платформере и прыжок и научить обрабатывать столкновения в sfml

Tags: sfml

как задать гравитацию в платформере и прыжок и научить обрабатывать столкновения в sfml.

```
RectangleShape *create_rect()
{
    RectangleShape rect_array[20];

    for (int i(0); i < 20; i++)
    {
        RectangleShape rect(Vector2f(32, 32));
        rect.setPosition(i * 32, 300);
        rect.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);
        rect_array[i] = rect;
    }
    return rect_array;
}


class Player
{
private:
    Image image;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
public:
    bool onGraund;
    float pos_x;
    float pos_y;
    float vel_x;
    float vel_y;
    float SPEED = 0.1;
    float bottom, left, top, right;
    char *direct;
    char *upping;
    float GRAV = 0.0005;
    bool jump;
    RectangleShape player_rect;

    Player()
    {

    }

    Player(char *file, float x, float y)
    {
        jump = false;
        onGraund = true;
        pos_x = x;
        pos_y = y;
        vel_x = 0;
        vel_y = 0;
        image.loadFromFile(file);
        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 52, 63));
        sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
        sprite.setScale(Vector2f(0.5, 0.5));

        player_rect.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
    }

    void update(float &t, RectangleShape *rect_array)
    {
        keys(t);
        gravity(t);
        if (!jump)
        {
            onGraund = true;        
        }
        collide(rect_array);
    }

    void keys(float &t)
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            vel_x = SPEED * t;
            pos_x += vel_x;
            sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
            direct = "right";
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            vel_x = -SPEED * t;
            pos_x += vel_x;
            sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
            direct = "left";
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            if (jump)
            {
                pos_y -= 100;
                sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
                jump = false;
            }
        }
    }
    void collide(RectangleShape *rect_array)
    {
        FloatRect sprite_rect = sprite.getGlobalBounds();
        for (int i(0); i < 200; i++)
        {
            FloatRect rect = rect_array[i].getGlobalBounds();
            if (sprite_rect.intersects(rect))
            {
                if (vel_y > 0)
                {
                    jump = true;
                    onGraund = false;
                    if (sprite_rect.top + sprite_rect.height > rect.top &&
                        sprite_rect.top < rect.top)
                    {

                        pos_y = rect.top - sprite_rect.height;
                        sprite.setPositio   n(sprite_rect.left, pos_y);
                        cout << "asas";
                        vel_y = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (vel_y < 0)
                {
                    pos_y = rect.top + rect.height;
                    vel_y = 0;
                    sprite.setPosition(rect.top + rect.height, pos_y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void gravity(float &t)
    {
        if (onGraund)
        {
            vel_y += GRAV * t;
            pos_y += vel_y * t;
            sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y);
        }
    }

    Sprite &GetSprite()
    {
        return sprite;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Clock clock;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "My Game");
    Player player(Mario_small, 100, 100);

    List earth_list;
    List brick_list;
    List earth_rect;

    RectangleShape rect_arr[200];
    int count = 0;


    for (int i(0); i < map_height; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < map_width; j++)
        {
            if (Map[i][j] == 'E')
            {
                RectangleShape rect(Vector2f(32, 32));
                rect.setPosition(j*32, i*32);
                rect.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);
                rect_arr[count] = rect;
                count++;
            }
            if (Map[i][j] == 'B')
            {
                Block brick1("brick", Brick_file1, j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE);
                brick_list.Add(brick1);
            }
        }
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
        clock.restart();
        time = time / 800;

        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        player.update(time, rect_arr);



        window.clear();

        earth_list.Blit(window);
        brick_list.Blit(window);

        for (int i(0); i < 200; i++)
        {
            window.draw(rect_arr[i]);
        }

        window.draw(player.GetSprite());

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```